# Complex numbers - equation

Tags: complex-numbers

$$z^2 = 13 + 84i$$

I have to find all solutions and write them in the **cartesian coordinate system**.

I have the $r = 85$. The angle is $\arctan 84/13$.

But what now?

Comment: Actually, the angle of $z$ is $\frac12\arctan{\frac{84}{13}}$, since $arg(z^2)=2arg(z)$

Comment: So I will use the angle of arctan 84/26, but this only gets me to the polar form, but I have to write it in the cartesian form.

Comment: Do you want/need to use the trigonometric form? It is simpler without, in my opinion.

Comment: @Questionnaire: $\tfrac{1}{2}\arctan\tfrac{84}{13}$ does not simplify to $\arctan\tfrac{84}{26}$.

Comment: Not quite. $\arctan\frac{84}{26}$ is not the same as $\frac12\arctan\frac{84}{13}.$

Comment: @Questionnaire Just convert the polar form to cartesian form i.e convert Euler form to, well, the other form.  If that counts as a hint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set $z=x+iy$, so the equation becomes $x^2-y^2+2ixy=13+84i$
and therefore
$$
\begin{cases}
x^2-y^2=13\\
2xy=84
\end{cases}
$$
From the second equation we get $y=42/x$ and substituting in the first equation gives
$$
x^2-\frac{1764}{x^2}=13
$$
or
$$
x^4-13x^2-1764=0
$$

The quadratic formula tells you that
$$
x^2=\frac{13+\sqrt{13^2+4\cdot 1764}}{2}=
\frac{13+85}{2}=49
$$
so $x=7$ or $x=-7$.

On the other hand, you could try completing the square at the beginning: $$
13+84i=13+2\cdot 7\cdot 6 i=49-36+2\cdot 7\cdot 6i=(7+6i)^2
$$

---

You can also use the trigonometric form, albeit in this case it's more complicated.

Since $13+84i$ is in the first quadrant, we can write it as
$$
13+84i=r(\cos\varphi+i\sin\varphi)
$$
where $r=\sqrt{13^2+84^2}=85$ and
$$
\varphi=\arctan\frac{84}{13}
$$
Thus the square root in the first quadrant can be written as
$$
\sqrt{85}(\cos(\varphi/2)+i\sin(\varphi/2))
$$
and the other square root is the opposite of this number.

However, showing
$$
\sqrt{85}\cos(\varphi/2)=7
$$
is not really the simplest thing.

Comment: Should I substitute and take the quadratic formula?

Comment: @Questionnaire Yes, set $t=x^2$. Only one solution is good, the positive one.

Comment: This works, but I don't think this utilizes r or the angle. It works, but exponential form is easier.

Comment: @amelia It depends on what you consider “easier”.

Comment: @egreg You're correct, 'easier' is subjective. I'll amend my statement to clarify: If the question is giving the r value and angle value, those are strong indicators that the question is asking for utilization of the Euler form. Both methods work.

Answer (score 2):

Let $z = re^{i\theta}$. Then, $z^2 = r^2e^{i2\theta} = 13+84i$. You've already determined that $r^2 = 85$ and $2\theta = \arctan\dfrac{84}{13}$. Trivially, $r^2 = 85$ gives us $r = \sqrt{85}$. So, now we just need to solve for $\theta$

Since $2\theta = \arctan\dfrac{84}{13}$, we have $\tan 2\theta = \dfrac{84}{13}$.

Then, using the identity $\tan 2\theta = \dfrac{2\tan \theta}{1-\tan^2\theta}$, we have $\dfrac{2\tan \theta}{1-\tan^2\theta} = \dfrac{84}{13}$.

Cross-multiply and move everything to one side to get $84\tan^2\theta+26\tan\theta-84 = 0$.

This can be factored as $2(7\tan\theta - 6)(6\tan\theta + 7) = 0$. So the solutions are $\tan \theta = \dfrac{6}{7}$ and $\tan\theta = -\dfrac{7}{6}$. But since we were originally solving $2\theta = \arctan\dfrac{84}{13}$, we can tell that $\tan\theta = -\dfrac{6}{7}$ is an extraneous solution. Hence, $\tan\theta = \dfrac{7}{6}$. From this, we get $\cos\theta = \pm\dfrac{7}{\sqrt{85}}$ and $\sin \theta = \pm\dfrac{6}{\sqrt{85}}$.

Therefore, $z = re^{i\theta} = r\cos\theta+ir\sin\theta = \pm(7+6i)$.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to find a solution here.

We can use a short formula or a longer algebraic method.

Let's try the algebraic method first.

We have $z^2=13+84i$

Our solution should be $$z=a+bi$$standard cartesian coordinates.

Let us use that as our substitution:$$z^2=13+84i$$$$(a+bi)^2=13+84i$$$$a^2-b^2+2abi=13+84i$$This is where we equate parts.  Simply put, we set the real parts equal and the imaginary parts equal:$$a^2-b^2=13$$$$2ab=84$$Simply systems of equations?$$4a^2b^2=84^2=7056$$$$a^2b^2=1764$$$$a^2=\frac{1764}{b^2}$$Substitute back into the other equation.$$a^2-b^2=13$$$$\frac{1764}{b^2}-b^2=13$$Multiply by $b^2$ and use quadratic formula.$$1764-b^4=13b^2$$$$0=b^4+13b^2-1764$$$$b^2=\frac{-13\pm\sqrt{169+7056}}{2}=\frac{-13\pm\sqrt{7225}}{2}$$$$b^2=\frac{-13\pm85}{2}$$$$b=\sqrt{\frac{-13\pm85}{2}}$$Recall one of the original formulas.$$a^2-b^2=13$$Substitute.$$a^2-\frac{-13\pm85}{2}=13$$$$a^2=13+\frac{-13\pm85}{2}=\frac{6.5\pm85}{2}$$$$a=\sqrt{\frac{6.5\pm85}{2}}$$$$z=a+bi=\frac{6.5\pm85}{2}+\frac{-13\pm85}{2}i$$

Second method is much easier.$$z^2=13+84i$$$$z=\sqrt{13+84i}$$Any complex number raised to a power is given as follows:$$(a+bi)^n=|a+bi|^n[\cos(n\theta)+i\sin(n\theta)]$$Note that square rooting is equal to exponenting by $.5$$$\sqrt{13+84i}=(13+84i)^{.5}$$$$z=85^{.5}[\cos(\arctan[\frac{42}{13})]+i\sin[\arctan(\frac{42}{13})]]$$

Comment: The first and second methods got 2 different results. Also, $\sqrt{289} = 17$.

Comment: I'm sorry.  I just used the angle measures the OP game me.  And thanks.

Comment: Sorry for the misinformation.

Comment: Now, your first method got answers of $z = 45.75+36i$ and $z = -39.25-49i$ while your second method got the answer $z \approx 2.726=8.807i$. Neither of these are correct. In your first method, you left off the square roots, and forgot to take out an extraneous solution. In the second method, the angle should have been $\tfrac{1}{2}\arctan\tfrac{84}{13}$ not $\arctan\tfrac{42}{13}$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint...set $z=a+ib$ and form and solve a simultaneous equation for $a, b\in \mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 0):

### Things you Know:

Basic forms of $z$: 
\begin{align*}
z & = x + iy\\
z & = re^{i\theta} = e^x \cdot e^y = r(\cos\theta + i\sin\theta)
\end{align*} 
From this (and a slightly longer derivation I'll exclude):
\begin{align*}
x & = r\cos\theta\\
y & = r\sin\theta 
\end{align*}

For exponents we have DeMoivre's Formula:

$$z^{\boldsymbol{n}} = r^{\boldsymbol{n}} \cdot e^{i\theta} = e^x \cdot e^y = r^{\boldsymbol{n}} (\cos \boldsymbol{n}\theta + i\sin \boldsymbol{n}\theta)$$
$z^n$ will still take on an $x+iy$ form, as all complex numbers do.
\begin{align*}
x & = r^n\cos(n\theta)\\
y & = r^n\sin(n\theta)
\end{align*}

### Solving it

\begin{align*}
z^2 & = 13 + i84 = x+iy\\
|z| & = r = \sqrt{85}\\
n & = 2
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
x & = 13 = r^n\cos(n\theta)\\
y & = 84 = r^n\sin(n\theta)
\end{align*}

Plug in for $r,n$ and solve for $n\theta$ by basic algebra and trig, making sure that $n\theta$ works for both $x$ and $y$ solutions. Once you have $n\theta$ divide it by $n$ for $\theta$ alone.

You now have $r$ and $\theta$ for $z$, so you can plug in and solve using the same formulas, but this time you're solving for $x$ and $y$ instead of $\theta$. 
\begin{align*}
x & = r\cos\theta\\
y & = r\sin\theta
\end{align*}

Now that you have $x,y$, you can write $z = x + iy$, and these are the cartesian coordinates. It's just a matter of using the exponential formulas forwards and backwards.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.